# karma getElementById null Error

Tags: javascript, html, karma-runner

In my javascript, document.getElementById always returns null in just case of run in karma. It's no problem when I load the html directly drop on browser. I think karma configuration is something wrong.

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sun Jul 26 2015 14:08:25 GMT+0900 (JST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: './',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['mocha'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'listtest.html',
  {pattern: 'js/*.js', included: false},
  {pattern: 'test/*.js', included: false}
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false
  })
}
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that karma could not include html files as default. To load html, html2js preprocessor is necessary. After convert html to js, karma can assign html to document object, but I don't know how to do that.